# xmlhttprequest request sent, but code not executed?

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

So, I am using a jQuery Upload-Script i've downloaded on the WWW.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
                {
                    var settings = {
                        url: "upload.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        allowedTypes:"pdf,xls,doc,docx,xlsx",
                        fileName: "name",
                        multiple: true,
                        onSuccess:function(files,data,xhr)
                        {
                            $("#status").html("<font color='green'>Upload is successed</font>");

                        },
                        onError: function(files,status,errMsg)
                        {
                            $("#status").html("<font color='red'>Upload is failed: " + errMsg + "</font>");
                        },
                        showDelete:true,
                        deleteCallback: function(data,pd)
                        {
                            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                            {
                                $.post("delete.php",{op:"delete",name:data[i]},
                                    function(resp, textStatus, jqXHR)
                                    {
                                        //Show Message
                                        $("#status").html("<font color='red'>File deleted.</font>");
                                    });
                            }
                            pd.statusbar.hide(); //You choice to hide/not.

                        }
                    };
                    $("#mulitplefileuploader").uploadFile(settings);

                });
```

And this is my "upload.php":

```
<?php
include_once("_assets/_pages/db.php");

$output_dir = "_files/";
if(isset($_FILES["myfile"]))
{
    $ret = array();

    $error = $_FILES["myfile"]["error"];
    //You need to handle  both cases
    //If Any browser does not support serializing of multiple files using FormData()
    if(!is_array($_FILES["myfile"]["name"])) //single file
    {
        $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$fileName);
        $ret[]= $fileName;
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO `Files` (FileName, UploadDate, DownloadCount) VALUES ($filename, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0)';
        $db->query($sql);
    }
    else  //Multiple files, file[]
    {
        $fileCount = count($_FILES["myfile"]["name"]);
        for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
        {
            $fileName = $_FILES["myfile"]["name"][$i];
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["myfile"]["tmp_name"][$i],$output_dir.$fileName);
            $ret[]= $fileName;
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `Files` (FileName, UploadDate, DownloadCount) VALUES ($filename, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0)';
            $db->query($sql);
        }

    }
    echo json_encode($ret);
}
?>
```

My upload.php is not putting the file into "_files/", nor inserting anything into my databse?
What am I doing wrong?

Other question: do you recommand any other well-designed (bootstrap-friendly) jQuery File-Upload handlers?

Comment: Any JS errors in the browser's console? What does the PHP return?

Comment: No JS errors, "Network" tells me that there was a good (code: 200) conenction to my upload.php. Files are now being uploaded smh, but nothing is stored in my db...

Comment: Yep code is 200, but what's the actual response of the PHP? Meaning, the data returned? PHP is looking for `isset($_FILES["myfile"])`, however, you never define anything named 'myfile' in your JS. My guess is that your `if(isset())` is purely skipped, no errors, status 200 OK.

Comment: Your guess is right, fileName inside setting{} had to be "myfile". Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, if no file is being shown... you might be missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

Comment: The file is being shown now. Only the "INSERT" isn't working now.

Comment: Try this, there was typo error... `INSERT INTO Files (FileName, UploadDate, DownloadCount) VALUES ('$fileName', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0)';`

Comment: Thanks Moid, that was the error. And yes CURRENT-TIMESTAMP is a MySQL expression and works.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is looking for isset($_FILES["myfile"]), however, you never define anything named 'myfile' in your JS. My guess is that your if(isset()) is purely skipped, no errors, status 200 OK.